# ¿Cómo puedo ignorar archivos en mi repositorio git ya habiendo declarado en el .gitIngore?

Tags: .net, git

Tengo un repositorio GIT con varios proyectos creado con .NET, con una estructura en capas donde cada capa esta guardada en sub carpetas, pero al  al compilar mi solución completa, en el repositorio me aparecen muchos archivos modificados que deberían ser ignorados.

Tales como la carpeta .vs/, obj/, bin/, entre otros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo de git ignore esta en la carpeta raíz de la solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro del archivo tengo las configuraciones que usaba en antiguos proyectos, la diferencia que tengo es que esta solución costa de varias soluciones guardadas en sub carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si están saliendo como modificados es porque ya git les estaba haciendo tracking con lo que `.gitignore` no tiene ningún efecto sobre ellos. Es el caso? Podrias saber mirando la lista de archivos en `HEAD` con `git ls-tree -r HEAD`. Si los archivos salen listados ahí, es por eso.

Comment: El código va como texto.